# Swift: Как осуществить переходы между двумя storyboard

Tags: swift

К примеру, у меня есть два storyboard (`Main.storyboard` и `Corect.storyboard`). У каждого есть свой ViewController (`ViewController.swift` и `CorectViewController.swift`).

Приложение стартует с `Main.storyboard` и в нём есть кнопка для перехода на `Corect.storyboard`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При создании контроллеров, вы можете указать из какого сториборда их загружать

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextViewController") as UIViewController
```

Answer (score 3):

День добрый!

1. Добавляете в `Main.storyboard` ссылку на **storyboard**
2. У добавленной ссылки устанавливаете на какой именно **storyboard** она должна ссылаться (`Corect.storyboard`)
3. Протягиваете сегвей от кнопки до ссылки.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Работает только если в storyboard ViewController, а если у меня в двух storyboard находится NavigationController. Тогда как быть?

Comment: Все равно работает. Navigation controller помечен как initial view controller во втором сторибоарде?